# Try to move UIImageView in screen with touchesMoved

Tags: objective-c, touchesmoved

I try to move 2 UIImageView.

Only one picture is supposed to move when I drag.

What I trying to accomplish is move UIImageView when I touch and drag the UIImageView.

This Is my viewDidLoad  :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
  myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100)];

 [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];

 [self.view addSubview:myImageView];


 myImageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 200,100)];

 [myImageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"]];

 [self.view addSubview:myImageView1]; 
}
```

This Is my touchesMoved method :

```
 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 // get touch event
 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

 CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

     for (UIImageView *image in [self.view subviews])
    {
       if ([touch view] == image)
       {
          // move the image view
          image.center = touchLocation;
       }

   }
}
```

In this line I don't get the images view

```
for (UIImageView *image in [self.view subviews])
```

It is possible to get the current touched UIIamgeView ?

Comment: This is not yet a question. You need to tell us more information, such as: 1. What are you trying to accomplish. 2. What is the current outcome? I'm guessing that you are trying to move just the `UIImageView` that contains the touch, but you need to be more specific and provide more details.

Comment: thanks I edit the post , and add more information.

Comment: You still haven't really told us what's going wrong.

Comment: Whats going wrong?? You mean u drag 2 pictures instead of one?

Comment: I can not move at the moment image, I try to move one image Every time the user pan the screen.

Answer (score 1):

There is methods you can use to drag UIImage's (or maybe other interface elements):

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event 
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

I suggest you to download and understand sample Apple app, that is design to illustrate drawing, touch handling, and animation using UIKit and Core Animation. There it is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html

Hope i that is helpful.

Comment: My problem is how to get the current UIIimageview that touch.

Comment: Roel you need to implement gesture recogniser, please take a read following tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more